# Process an array result of a promise with a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

I have the following code which works in synchronized way:

```
function getFoldersOf(dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir).map(p => path.join(dir, p)).filter(p => fs.lstatSync(p).isDirectory());
}
```

Now think of using these API (The provided function don't exist in node. These are hypotethical and I have to write them):

- `fs.readdirSync -> fs.readdirAsync`
- `path.join -> path.joinAsync`
- `fs.lstatSync -> fs.lstatAsync`

My question is that what is the proper way of converting this function to async?

*PS: I suspect that I can solve this problem easily with reactive extensions!*

Comment: I know. This is hypothetical. I want to replace node api with something I write by myself.

Comment: I am rewriting node api to use them in client side. So I need to convert them to async version.

Comment: @alisabzevari how are you intending to support file system operations client side?

Comment: If I needed to make them async I will.

Comment: @alisabzevari please elaborate in your question what exactly it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @robertklep actually my problem is that I am writing an electrion app. My problem with electron is its installation size. It is somehow bloated. I am thinking to create a small node client/server app or a chrome app (thinking of a desktop app that loads in browser). So I am converting my logic code to something that could work with various frameworks (node, chrome, asp.net, electron). So I need a file api which works async and I want to work with it in my JS app logic

Comment: [`path.joinAsync`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2)???

Comment: @Bergi - yes, apparently the OP is desperate to asynchronise the whole of javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to implement your file system API so each operation returns a  [`bluebird`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) promise, which already provides helpers like [`.map()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/map.html) and [`.filter()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/filter.html).

For example, to turn the Node `fs` API into one that uses `bluebird` promises, you can use [`.promisifyAll()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html):

```
// node-fs.js
var Promise    = require('bluebird');
module.exports = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
```

To use this (when running your app in Node):

```
// app.js
var path = require('path');
var fs   = require('./node-fs');

function getFoldersOf(dir) {
  return fs.readdirAsync(dir)
           .map(   p => path.join(dir, p))
           .filter(p => fs.lstatAsync(p).then(d => d.isDirectory()));
}
```

Comment: What if path.join is also async. The rest of you solution works perfectly.

Comment: @alisabzevari the code wouldn't have to change if `path.join()` is async, provided that it also returned a promise.

Comment: I ask again, why the heck would `path.join` need to ever be async - asynchronicity serves a specific purpose, to asynchronise functions just on a whim is pointless

Comment: @JaromandaX It is not pointless. Joining paths is a platform specific operation and I don't want to make my client side dependent to a platform.

Comment: Oh my. What does that have to do with it being synchronous?

Comment: @JaromandaX in Node it's a synchronous operation, but for other platforms that OP wants to support it may not be.